# Use pytrend to return results over the past 12 months

Tags: python, google-trends

The function pytrend.interest_over_time() returns results for every week. How can I return results for the past year? Here is my input:

```
pytrend.build_payload(
    kw_list=[companies[0], companies[1], companies[2], companies[3], companies[4]])
df = pytrend.interest_over_time()
print(df.head(10))
```

Output:

```
Walmart  Amazon  Apple Inc.  CVS Health  ExxonMobil  isPartial
date                                                                      
2016-07-10       18      54           0           0           0      False
2016-07-17       17      47           0           0           0      False
2016-07-24       18      49           0           0           0      False
2016-07-31       18      49           0           0           0      False
2016-08-07       16      48           0           0           0      False
2016-08-14       16      45           0           0           0      False
2016-08-21       16      48           0           0           0      False
2016-08-28       17      49           0           0           0      False
2016-09-04       17      49           0           0           0      False
2016-09-11       16      48           0           0           0      False

[Done] exited with code=0 in 3.963 seconds
```

I want the output just for 2020. I haven't been able to find this answer through google searches or in pytrend's documentation: https://pypi.org/project/pytrends/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use timeframe parameter to specify start and end date, Following code snippet will solve your problem

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq

pytrend = TrendReq()
pytrend.build_payload(kw_list=['Walmart','Amazon','Apple Inc.','CVS Health','ExxonMobil'],timeframe = '2020-01-01 2020-12-31')
df = pytrend.interest_over_time()
print(df.head(10))
```

More details about the parameter is available in documentation of pytrends(link attached in question) check this attached screenshot for reference
[image]

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I couldn't find those parameters, but this is very helpful!

Comment: How do I get the average for the course of a year? I'm still getting several outputs, and if I were to average them myself then Apple, CVS, and Exxon would all be zero. On the google trends page (https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=US&gprop=news&q=%2Fm%2F0841v,%2Fm%2F0mgkg,%2Fm%2F0k8z,%2Fm%2F02q9wld,%2Fm%2F02s6x) I get the average across the year in a bar graph on the left. How can I get this average?

Comment: How are you calculating the average? The value in the bar graph is the average of all the values for that keyword, which you can directly calculate, I didn't get that how are you getting zero as average?